# Prove: we always have at least x>0 is a $x^3+bx^2+cx-d^2=0$ 's root

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Prove: we always have at least one x>0 is a  $x^3+bx^2+cx-d^2=0$ 's root (b, c, d are real numbers and $d≠0$)

Comment: discriminant   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function

Comment: I think you need $d \neq 0$ for strict inequality.  What happens at $x=0$ and $x \to \infty$?

Comment: Yes $d≠0$, sorry

Comment: Use Descartes' rule of signs.

Answer (score 1):

The statement you mentioned does not hold when d is allowed to be zero. Consider $x^3$ as a counterexample.I will assume that d is different from zeroLet p(x) be the polynomial.thus p(0)<0. Since p(x) tends to infinity as x goes to infinity. Therefore there exists r>0 such that p(r)>0. Now apply the intermediate value theorem on the interval [0,r]

Answer (score 1):

Let,
$$p(x) = x^3 + bx^2 + cx - d^2$$
Then we have, $p(0)= -d^2 < 0$
We know that there exists $x > 0$ so that:
$$x^3 > bx^2 + cx - d^2$$
For any set of constants $b, c, d$. Let's call this pont $r$. Thus, we know that $p(0) < 0$ and $p(r)>0$ and that $r > 0$.

You can continue the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=x^3+bx^2+cx-d^2$,

using [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DescartesSignRule.html), there is only one change of sign in $f(x),$ so $f(x)$ can have at most one positive real root and the number of positive real root will be exactly one as [the number of positive roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Positive_roots) of the polynomial=the number of sign changes$(m)-2\cdot n$, where $0\le 2n\le m$.